# how joomla htaccess identifies what is the get method for particular alias?

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, alias

Im developing a website which supports SEF urls. I use PHP as serverside language. I know htaccess basic codes how works with it. But the problem is if I want to rewrite a php get link I have to put each both links on htaccess like this.

```
RewriteRule ^sign-in$ index.php?view=signin
RewriteRule ^register$ index.php?view=register
RewriteRule ^jobs$ index.php?id=2
```

Is there any possible way to automate urls with htaccess and url particular alias instead of adding Rewrite rules manually? something like joomla? I was trying to understand how joomla htaccess connects with particual alias. But I still couldn't understand how it works. I cant uderstand how joomla htaccess makes relationship with article aliases. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there isn't any difference for how an `id` looks like compared to how a `view` looks like (in your example, `register` is a `view` and `jobs` is an `id=2`), then you have to do one or the other individually:

To "automate" the views you could try just doing this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# all id's here:
RewriteRule ^jobs$ index.php?id=2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^something-else$ index.php?id=3 [L]
RewriteRule ^another$ index.php?id=4 [L]

# this will do all views
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?view=$1 [L]
```

---

EDIT: If you need to do these mappings via an external set of aliases, you need to take a look at the [`RewriteMap` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap). You will need to have access to the server or vhost configs in order to setup the map, but your rules can stay in an htaccess file.

Say you have a text file called "joomla_maps.txt" that looks like:

```
jobs id=2
another id=3
sign-in view=sign-in
register view=register
```

etc...

You can use that mapping by setting it up in a `RewriteMap` (in vhost/server config)

```
RewriteMap joomla txt:/path/to/joomla_maps.txt
```

And later in your htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?${joomla:$1} [L]
```

Take a look through the `RewriteMap` docs to get some examples of other kinds of maps, including executing a script or using a dbm hash map.

Comment: Thanks a lot jon Lin. But What I want is,

Other than adding everything on htaccess file, I'm looking for a method that can have ability to fetch alias from database.

as an example, joomla use the method I'm looking for. I can't understand how to implement that method into my site. Joomla doesn't put all article aliases and article ids on the htaccess. They use another method. I guess they fetch article id, alias from the database. The problem is how they make relation to htaccess with the alias and particular article id? If I know their method I think my problem will solve it. Thanks again.

Comment: @KasunMalith I've edited the answer to include details of using `RewriteMap`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this. But always errors. Here my last question. It seems like joomla doesn't use RewriteMap. because I cant find any similar code on joomla htaccess file. If you know please tell me what is their method that they use to fetch aliases from database and connect them with htaccess.
Thank you!